# ¿Cómo obtener una lista de idiomas que están definidos en la App en Android?

Tags: java, android

Por ejemplo una aplicación que la tengamos los recursos en diferentes idiomas

```
values/=> están en ingles (los defecto de la app)
values-es/ => están en español
values-it/ => están en italiano
etc...
```

Si tenemos una zona de configuración donde el usuario, pueda escoger con un spinner el idioma de la app

```
automático => seria el por defecto que está definido al dispositivo
español
italiano
```

Cómo se podría crear un array (key,value) para poblar el contenido para el selector de idioma.

Es decir que los pille automáticamente partiendo de los recursos que tengamos establecidos en la app.

**resultado ejemplo**

```
default = automático
en = inglés
es = español
it = italiano
```

Me estoy mirando lo siguiente [get-the-applications-resources-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611065/get-the-applications-resources-languages)

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources r = getResources();
    Configuration c = r.getConfiguration();
    String[] loc = r.getAssets().getLocales();
    for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
        //Log.d("LOCALE", i + ": " + loc[i]);

        c.locale = new Locale(loc[i]);
        Resources res = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, c);
        String s1 = res.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);
        c.locale = new Locale("");
        Resources res2 = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, c);
        String s2 = res2.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);

        if(!s1.equals(s2)){
            Log.d("DIFFERENT LOCALE", i + ": "+ s1+" "+s2 +" "+ loc[i]);
        }
    }
```

Devuelve DIFFERENT LOCALE los `es, it` pero el `en` no lo detecta.

Comment: Será porque el `en` siempre esta presente... ya que es el idioma con el que el sistema sale de "fabrica"

Comment: Veo una diferencia con la pregunta que vinculaste, es que ha declarado `values-en` en lugar de `values` solo.

Comment: @Hector pues si es la razón para que no la puede detectar.

Comment: @md se puede tener todos los values localizados? es decir que no hayan values/ a solas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptando un poco de una de las [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611065/get-the-applications-resources-languages) de SO, he creado la función `getAppLanguages` que devuelve una lista de los idiomas que se definen en la App, pero se debe especificar el primero de todo, el que definimos por defecto en la App.

```
public static Map<String, String> getAppLanguages(Context context, String appDefaultLang) {
    Map<String, String> listAppLocales = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    listAppLocales.put("default", "Auto");

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    String[] listLocates = res.getAssets().getLocales();

    for (String locate : listLocates) {
        Log.i("Member name: ",locate);
    }


    for (String locate : listLocates) {
        conf.locale = new Locale(locate);
        Resources res1 = new Resources(context.getAssets(), metrics, conf);
        String s1 = res1.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);
        String value = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%s (%s)",
                ucfirst(conf.locale.getDisplayName()),
                conf.locale.getLanguage()
        );

        conf.locale = new Locale("");
        Resources res2 = new Resources(context.getAssets(), metrics, conf);
        String s2 = res2.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);

        if (!s1.equals(s2)) {
            //Log.d("DIFFERENT LOCALE", i + ": "+ s1+" "+s2 +" "+ loc[i]);
            listAppLocales.put(locate, value);
        } else if (locate.equals(appDefaultLang)) {
            listAppLocales.put(locate, value);
        }
    }
    return listAppLocales;
}

public static String ucfirst(String subject) {
    if (!subject.isEmpty()) {
        return Character.toUpperCase(subject.charAt(0)) + subject.substring(1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

**Su uso**

Si el idioma base de la aplicación es decir el por defecto es inglés, debemos especificarlo así.

```
Map<String,String> listAppLanguages = getAppLanguages(this,"en);
```

Datos que devolverá:

```
default:Auto
en:English
es:Spanish
it:Italian
```

Comment: debe ser  getAppLanguages(this,"en");  =)

Comment: tu pregunta se refería a obtener los idiomas definidos en los folders por ejemplo: values/ values-es/  values-it/   con esto se obtienen?

Comment: sip @Elenasys, obtener una lista de lo que se especifican internamente, si se te ocurre una manera más simple, porque ese método digamos no me acaba de cuajar.