# ¿Cómo meter contenido en un ListPreference con Java en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

En el layout pref_general.xml tengo un `ListPreference` para escoger el idioma de la App.

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="language"
    android:defaultValue="default"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_title_dialog_sel_language"
    android:entries="@array/pref_language_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_language_list_values"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_sel_language" />
```

Pero quiero que `entries` y `entryValues` se deben poblar desde el array obtenido de `getAppLanguages()` definida en [¿Cómo obtener una lista de idiomas que están definidos en la App en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10187/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-una-lista-de-idiomas-que-est%C3%A1n-definidos-en-la-app-en-android)

La función devuelve datos con esa estructura:

```
Map<String,String)
//valores que puede devolver la función
default:Auto
en:English
es:Spanish
it:Italian
```

Necesito poblar dinámica-mente un `ListPreference` es decir desde código Java.
Separar del map por partes `value` para `entries` y el `key` para los `entryValues`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado!**
Para crear un ListPrefrence dinámicamente, a partir de un `Map<key,value>`

layout.xml

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="language"
    android:defaultValue="default"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_title_dialog_sel_language"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_sel_language" />
```

Dentro del método OnCreate

```
        final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
        setListPreferenceData(listPreference);
```

función setListPreferenceData

```
private static void setListPreferenceData(ListPreference lp) {
    Map<String,String> listSupportLanguages = Utils.getAppLanguages(MyApplication.getAppContext(),"en");

    List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key: listSupportLanguages.keySet()) {
        listValues.add(listSupportLanguages.get(key));
    }

    CharSequence[] entries = listValues.toArray(new CharSequence[listValues.size()]);
    CharSequence[] entryValues = listSupportLanguages.keySet().toArray(new CharSequence[listSupportLanguages.size()]);

    lp.setEntries(entries);
    lp.setEntryValues(entryValues);
    lp.setDefaultValue("default");
}
```

**Referéncias:**

[¿Cómo obtener una lista de idiomas que están definidos en la App en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10187/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-una-lista-de-idiomas-que-est%C3%A1n-definidos-en-la-app-en-android)

[¿Cómo obtener context dentro de un método static en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10267/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-context-dentro-de-un-m%C3%A9todo-static-en-android)

**Método alternativo**

Otra forma para crear un selector de idiomas, que consume menos recursos, es pasar un array de los idiomas que soporta la App, solo es necesario especificar el código `ISO 639-1`

```
<string-array name="pref_language_list_values">
    <item>default</item>
    <item>es</item>
    <item>en</item>
    <item>it</item>
</string-array>
```

Función `getAppSupportedLaungages`

```
public static String[] getAppSupportedLaungages(Context context, String[] langs) {

    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

    String[] displayNames = new String[langs.length];
    displayNames[0] = "Auto";
    int size = langs.length;
    for (int i=1; i < size; i++) {
        conf.locale = new Locale(langs[i]);
        displayNames[i] = ucFirst(conf.locale.getDisplayName());
    }

    return displayNames;
}

public static String ucFirst(String subject) {
    if (!subject.isEmpty()) {
        return Character.toUpperCase(subject.charAt(0)) + subject.substring(1);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

función `setListPreferenceData`

```
private static void setListPreferenceData(ListPreference lp) {

    String[] entryValues = MyApplication.getAppContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_language_list_values);
    CharSequence[] entries = Utils.getAppSupportedLaungages(MyApplication.getAppContext(), entryValues);

    lp.setEntries(entries);
    lp.setEntryValues(entryValues);
    lp.setDefaultValue("default");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple desde mi punto de vista seria crearte Switch y rellenar dinamicamente los entries y values en base al valor recibido.

```
 CharSequence[] entries;
 CharSequence[] entryvalues;
        switch (language){
            case "italian":
                entries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.italian_entries);
                entryvalues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.italian_entry_values);
            case "spanish":
                entries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spanish_entries);
                entryvalues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spanish_entry_values);
            case "english":
                entries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.english_entries);
                entryvalues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.english_entry_values);

        }
 myListPreference.setEntries(entries);
 myListPreference.setDefaultValue("1");
 myListPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues);
```

En caso de que te devuelva un array muy extenso de valores, podrías declararte un array en xml con el idioma, y el array de entries y values correspondiente para cada uno, y en base a eso, llamarlo para realizar lo mismo que en el ejemplo de arriba pero sin crear un Switch gigantesco.

Espero que te sea de ayuda!

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, la idea de obtenerlos con la función getAppLanguages es para no tener que crear array XML entries y values, que si se agrega un values-ru, no tenga que cambiar nada ya que lo pillaría automáticamente.
Parte de tú código me sirve,

Comment: Si la funcion de getAppLanguages te devuelve un único array por idioma, por que no usas ese array para rellenar los EntryValues y usas uno generico para el de entries?

Comment: debo separar el array(key,value) keys que serán los entryvalues y value los entries, con tu parte final diría que ya lo solvento,

Comment: Genial ;) Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si te ha sido de ayuda!

Comment: Francisco ya te +1 en tu respuesta