# ¿Cómo obtener context dentro de un método static en Android?

Tags: java, android

Hay alguna forma de obtener el `context` dentro de un método definido cómo `static`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma para realizar esto es crear una clase que extienda de Application, la cual contendría un método estatico para obtener el contexto:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class App extends Application {

    private static Application myApplication;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return sApplication;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myApplication = this;
    }
}
```

Podemos acceder desde otro punto de la aplicación al contexto, de la siguiente forma:

```
App.getContext()
```

Pero el método más sencillo, es definido a partir de la construcción de la mayoría de las aplicaciones que tienen una actividad principal que es definida como `MAIN`, se agregan dos métodos a el `MainActivity`, para obtener la instancia de la actividad accesandola estaticamente:.

```
private static MainActivity myContext

public MainActivity() {
    myContext =  this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return myContext
}
```

Podemos acceder desde otro punto de la aplicación al contexto, de la siguiente forma:

```
MainActivity.getInstance()
```

Comment: Holas Elenasys, perfecto, más detallado y optimizada, que mi solución traducida

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo uso el segundo método, esto por simplicidad personal pero siempre hay que evaluar que usar, la instancia de la actividad o la de la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar con lo siguiente:

En el `AndroidManifest.xml` declarar que la aplicación se extiende de una clase `MyAplication`

```
<application android:name="tu.package.name.MyApplication">
....
</application>
```

La clase MyApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Cuando se quiere referirse al contexto de la aplicación dentro de un método declarado `static`

```
MyApplication.getAppContext() //para obtener el contexto de forma estática
```

Traducido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

¿Puedes dar algún detalle más? El código de tu clase con el método `static`, el contexto donde lo utilizas...

Otra opción es pasar el contexto a tu método

```
public static miMetodo(Context context, ...){
    context.function();
}
```

Comment: Si es lo que normalmente uso, pero si usas miMetodo des de otro método declarado static, tienes que ir pasando el context a cada uno, y de la siguiente forma que he encontrado, te puedes saltar ese preoceso, te doy +1

Answer (score 0):

La más fácil y mejor forma de obtener el context de una Activity es colocándole el `.this` después de su nombre. Por ejemplo: Si el nombre de tu Activity es `SecondActivity`, su context sería `SecondActivity.this`